# Hibernate 3 to 4 migration (join column length)

Tags: hibernate

During the migration from hibernate 3.6 to 4.3, the generated creation script failed because
 Column length were incorrect for the join columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i override TableBinder class, changing that

```
while ( mappedByColumns.hasNext() ) {
            Column column = (Column) mappedByColumns.next();
            columns[0].overrideFromReferencedColumnIfNecessary( column );
            columns[0].linkValueUsingAColumnCopy( column, value );
    }
```

to ->

```
while ( mappedByColumns.hasNext() ) {
            Column column = (Column) mappedByColumns.next();
            int length = column.getLength();
            if (columns[0].getMappingColumn().getLength()!=255)
                column.setLength(columns[0].getMappingColumn().getLength());                
            columns[0].overrideFromReferencedColumnIfNecessary( column );
            columns[0].linkValueUsingAColumnCopy( column, value );              
    }
```

its not a perfect solution, but its fully working to me